# Why isn't msg.sender.send getting called?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-debugging

### Contract code:

```
function rand( uint256 seedB ) returns (uint256){ 
    
    //define seedA variable
    uint256 seedA = 1;
    
    uint amount = 1 finney;
    
    if (seedA == seedB) { 
        msg.sender.send(amount);
    }
    

    return seedA + seedB; 
}
```

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e210a052b6b4c86337c2

Basically, if `SeedA` (which equals 1) equals `SeedB` it sends `amount` to msg.sender.

---

Why does this not work, when I am calling the function using:

```
random.rand.sendTransaction(1,
    {from: eth.accounts[0], 
    value: web3.toWei(.0001, 'ether'), 
    to: '0x4abc14efad9a7a84a0a9ef6e1a782c43a9e3f550', 
    gas: 500000,  data: web3.fromAscii('message')})
```

Here is the contract address:
https://www.etherchain.org/account/0x4abc14efad9a7a84a0a9ef6e1a782c43a9e3f550

Am I invoking the contract improperly in the sendTransaction? I am invoking it from inside my local geth client.

How do I ensure my parameter (1) is passed into the contract function `rand` via sendTransaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your contract you are trying to send 1 finney, but you are only providing your contract with 0.1 finney...  A Finney is 0.001 ETH, not 0.0001

Comment: OMG. My code has been working all day. You do not want to know how long I have been trying to work this out. I have stripped back my code to bare basics because of this error LOOOOL THANK YOU. 
It now works, you can see the first sent tx from the contract address:
https://www.etherchain.org/account/0x4abc14efad9a7a84a0a9ef6e1a782c43a9e3f550#txreceived

Comment: No problem. You can also use "finney" as the units in web3.fromWei

Comment: Also, you don't need to put the `to:` field in the tx object. It gets filled in automatically

Answer (score 2):

Try `web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]`

and then `random.rand.sendTransaction(1)`

Comment: The transactions are going through, just I am not seeing that seedA == seedB because if it did it would send me 1 Finney.

Answer (score 2):

It might be because you supply `data` when calling `sendTransaction` on an actual function, overriding the function identifier and the function argument you gave (`1`).